# Using jquery, how can I hide all table rows that are not checked?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, filter

I have a html table with a column of checkboxes.  I have a button (that says "Show only selected rows" and on the button click I want to hide all rows where the checkbox in that row is not checked

Here is an example of my html:

```
 <button id="mybutton">Show only Selected Rows</button>

<table>
      <tr>
          <td>test</td>
          <td><input class="test" type=checkbox value=100></td>
          <td><input class="test2" type=checkbox value=222></td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>test</td>
          <td><input class="test" type=checkbox value=100></td>
          <td><input class="test2" type=checkbox value=222></td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

I want to have it dynamically look at a column (not hard coded) so i can say "filter based on 2nd column or 3rd column, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You Are looking for this......

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
$('table tr td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').hide();
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
body {background-color: rgb(248,248,248)}
#nav {
    list-style:none;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:500;
}
/* this is the parent menu */
 #nav li a {
    display:block;
    padding:15px;
    color:#000;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
    
}
 #nav a.open {
    color:#fff;
    background-color: pink;
}
 #nav ul {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav ul li {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
 #nav ul a {
    display:block;
    height:15px;
    padding: 15px;
    color:#666;
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.active{
    background-color: pink;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="mybutton">Show only Selected Rows</button>
<table>
      <tr>
          <td><input class="test"  type=checkbox checked value=100></td>
          <td><input class="test2" type=checkbox checked value=222></td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input class="test" type=checkbox   value=100></td>
          <td><input class="test2"  type=checkbox checked  value=222></td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selector `:checkbox:not(:checked)` to target all unchecked checkboxes along with `.closest('tr')` to get their parent tr:

```
$('table td:first-child :checkbox:not(:checked)').closest('tr').hide();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4hgqo1j/)**

Comment: I realized i have other checkboxes in the table so how could i scope this check to a single column in the table?

Comment: do you mean first column in each row or all checkboxes in first row??

Comment: I have a column with a checkbox in each cell and I want to have the filter logic just look at this one column to determine whether to filter

Comment: i am confused. can you elaborate with complete markup and expected result.

Comment: I updated my question.  So in this case i have two columns of checkboxes but i want to filter the rows only based on whether the first column checkbox is checked (not the second)

Comment: see my updated questions, i want to avoid it being hard coded to the first column